# protractor chromedriver version (CLI vs VSC) error

Tags: protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I had error because of using old chromedriver. So I used:

- webdriver-manager clean
- webdriver-manager update
- webdriver-manager status
  To update and verirfy chromedriver version 89.0.4389.90

If I run protractor from command line, all tests passed. So OK.
But If I run protractor from visual studio mode pressing F5 (debug).
I am faced to this error:

```
E/launcher - Error: SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 87 
Current browser version is 89.0.4389.90 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
    
Driver info: chromedriver=87.0.4280.20 (c99e81631faa0b2a448e658c0dbd8311fb04ddbd-refs/branch-heads/4280@{#355}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.19042 x86_64
```

I donť know why because chromedriver should be already updated to version 89.0.4389.90 via webdriver-manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

webdriver manager is an npm package. Any npm package can have 2 different installations - global and local.

Imagine you have multiple projects. For first one you want to use protractor 5.4 for another one protractor 7. So you would just installed them the way every project had its own local protractor.

Then you start working on third project, but you don't install protractor locally. Then it will go to your global packages to see if protractor is there

Apparently your VSC is configured to use local package. And when you run `protractor conf.js` that will refer to global one.

Use these steps to update your local webdriver manager
[How can I revert Protractor back to a selected version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65183276/how-can-i-revert-protractor-back-to-a-selected-version/65183920#65183920)

Comment: let me know if you still uncertain how to proceed

Comment: I checked packages which are installed globally: -- protractor@7.0.0, -- typescript@4.1.3
It seems, that I have two protractor installation, one global (c:\Users*****\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor) and second local (project\node_modules\protractor).
If I run webdriver-manager status, it's mapped to global.
If I run protractor from cmd, it's also mapped to global.
But If I run protractor from VSC it is mapped to local installation and also old version of chromedriver.
So, I guess I should to remove global protractor installation?

Comment: you actually need to update local webdriver manager and chromedriver. PLease upvote if this is helpful

Comment: I tried to run `webdriver-manager update` from several places but everytime it refers to global instalation. How to update local installation? Thank you.

Comment: I think I actually answered this already here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65183920/9150146 try and let me know

Comment: yes, you are right. From directory: project\node_modules\.bin\
I ran `webdriver-manager update` and chromedriver is locally updated.
Thank you